# get the xmlnode value

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I have a xml below
First I will do a SelectNode to select .Then I want to do a foreach on two selected nodes and then select  for each one respectively.

```
    <Root>
    <persons>
     <Number>2525</Number>
     <Number>2626</Number>
      <persons>
        <Number>2828</Number>
        <Number>2929</Number>
      </persons>
    </persons>
    </Root>
```

When running the foreach for the first time,I am getting Age and Name for both Arpit and Tushar using the Xpath =

```
XmlNodeList outcomelist = each.SelectNodes(".//*[local-name()='persons']/*[local-name()='Number']");
```

"each" is the current node.

Please help to write the xpath correctly so that I can get the values only for the current node and excluding the child node.

Please note that this xml is only for example purpose.The real xml is very big and tedious to parse.

Comment: So are you saying you want to get the values for the `Number`s under any top-level `persons`, but not the descendant ones?

Comment: yes that is correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to spend some time getting familiar with XPath because you're using "whatever works" techniques like `//` and `*[local-name() = '...']`, and this is getting you into trouble.

To select the top level `persons`, this XPath should work:

```
XmlNodeList persons = each.SelectNodes("/Root/persons/Number");
```

If your XML uses namespaces, then you *can* do this to select the name:

```
XmlNodeList age = 
  each.SelectNodes("/*/*[local-name() = 'persons']/*[local-name() = 'Number']");
```

but as I alluded above, this is a hack and what you should really do in this case is handle namespaces properly.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply..My question itself was not matching with the situation which I was facing.Actually there are multiple nodes nested.I have edited the question now.Could you please help with that.Thanks in advance.